# React component classes meta-programming

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working with React and using React-Bootstrap components.

I found some issues in the React-Bootstrap library which I "fixed" (or "workarounded") by editing the react-bootstrap.js file. The problem is that if tomorrow a new version of react-bootstrap comes out, then I will have to copy-paste/re-write/whatever all the code I wrote in the react-bootstrap.js file to the new one. I don't want to do this, so I'm wandering if there is a way to modify the component classes (i.e. change the render function) provided by react-bootstrap without touching the react-bootstrap.js file. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this, or at least I'm not finding easy to understand the inner working of the component classes. Any ideas on how could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It'd be better to edit the [source](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) and build your own version.  Using git allows you to merge changes on the main repo.  You can also send a pull request if you'd like them to consider including it in the main project.

Comment: I don't think I have enough JS, Bootstrap or React experience to make a valuable contribution to the project. Also, I'm not familiar with the development tools involved, etc... I'd rather just report issues and make minor tweaks/fixes in my project. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a wrapping component, that overrides methods of the original component after it's mounted:

```
    function wrapComponent (originalComponent, override) {
        return React.createClass({
            componentDidMount: function () {
                for (var property in override) {
                    if (override.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        this.refs.original[property] = override[property];
                    }
                }
            },
            render: function () {
                return this.transferPropsTo(
                    <originalComponent ref="original">{ this.props.children }</originalComponent>
                );
            }
        });
    }

    var ConsoleSample = React.createClass({
        // This method can still be used:
        prefix: function (text) {
            return "prefix: " + text;
        },
        // This method will be overridden:
        output: function (text) {
            console.log(this.prefix(text));
        },
        onClick: function () {
            this.output("Hello world");
        },
        render: function () {
            return <button onClick={this.onClick}>{ this.props.children }</button>
        }
    });

    var Application = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            var AlertSample = wrapComponent(ConsoleSample, { 
                output: function (text) {
                    alert(this.prefix(text));
                }
            });
            return <div>
                <ConsoleSample>This should console.log</ConsoleSample>
                <AlertSample>This should alert</AlertSample>
            </div>
        }
    });

    React.renderComponent(<Application />, document.body.lastChild);
```

It's a simple hack though.  I'd agree that the correct solution is to fork React-Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer :) I was thinking in modifying the class directly using some sort of reflection. Something like having a react-bootstrap-fixes.js file, where I could just set my new methods for the classes and then forget about it. Isn't that possible? Is it necessary to modify the instance once mounted? Wrapping components every time I want to use them seems pretty messy...

Comment: Oh, wait... I misunderstood. You are creating a new class which overrides the method of its "inner class" when mounted, is it? That's less messy indeed... But still, I'd prefer to modify the class directly. Do you know if that's possible and/or how to do it?

Comment: Are you planning to override all their classes? I hope not. A few hacks is all right, using my solution, but I would recommend forking if you're changing a lot. By the way you can also just write plain bootstrap HTML for those few components :)

Comment: No, I inserted a couple of fixes, no more than that. I'm using this hack now, but I'm having trouble with some references... I don't really know how the bootstrap-react file is generated/works, but there are references which I can't get from my "fixes" file, such as "classSet" (seems to be imported(?) from "utils/classSet"). Any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you using browserify's require()? Then try: `var classSet = require('react-bootstrap/utils/classSet');` otherwise just copy that tiny file: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/utils/classSet.js

Comment: Great! It's working now! I just copied the file. Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Oh, and there's a little tweak missing. If you override the "render" function or some other function which is called from "render", you must call "forceUpdate()", since you are overriding it after it was called.

Comment: I'd be interested to see your final version of `wrapComponent()` in the above example. You can also generate a proper `this.constructor.displayName` for the wrapper component.

Comment: At the moment, I'm using exactly what you proposed. I only added the this.forceUpdate() at the end of the componentDidMount method. Also, to be able to use RequireJS with this I defined a module which requires react-bootstrap, modifies the original react-bootstrap module and returns it directly. It's working fine, but I would like to be able to modify the proper component class, since I'm rendering all "fixed" components twice.

Comment: Almost forgot... It would be useful to be able to modify mixins (like BootstrapMixin) without touching the source file. Otherwise, I'm forced to "fix" every class that uses a specific mixin using your hack.

Comment: Rygu, I'm having problems replacing the render method for the Panel component. If you replace it with exactly the same and unmodified method, the "collapsable" feature doesn't work. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No, nothing in the console... :/ May be the "this" reference is causing problems? Or may the use of the "refs" property to implement collapsing of the Panel component is causing it...